# How to link a library with clang and llvm-link

Tags: c++, c, makefile, llvm

I am compiling my program like this,

```
clang++ -O4 -emit-llvm file1.cpp -c -o file1.bc -pthread 
clang++ -O4 -emit-llvm file2.cpp -c -o file2.bc -pthread

llvm-link file1.bc file2.bc -o main.ll -S
```

How do I specify linking with **-ldl**

Comment: Did you try `clang++ -o main.ll file1.bc file2.vs -ldl` ?

Comment: No that doesn't work, it says unknown command line

Comment: file2.vs is a typo on my side but I guess you fixed it. You should post the whole error log because clang is able to link.

Comment: It says this: llvm-link: Unknown command line argument '-ldl'.  Try: 'llvm-link -help'
llvm-link: Did you mean '-d'?

Comment: Could you show exactly what you typed? @İsmail'cartman'Dönmez 's suggestion should work.

Answer (score 3):

`llvm-link` is a program which "links" together LLVM IR files into a single IR file; you can read more about it [here](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-link.html). It does not have any relation to `ld` or to linking object files together.

If you do want to generate object code and/or executables, see these related questions:

- [How to generate machine code with llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13464259/242762)
- [llvm-link with external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12685976/242762)

In short, you should be using native tools for assembling and linking (`as` and `ld`, for instance), though there is currently some experimental support for generating object files and for linking in LLVM.

In any case, Clang itself can invoke a platform linker - that is actually the default, but of course you have overridden by providing `-c`.