# How to link a library with llvm-link

Tags: c, gcc, llvm, clang

I am using `llvm-link` to link LLVM bitcode files, but in my source code I also want to use a function from a shared library file that I created. Now, how do I go about linking that shared library with `llvm-link`? If I can't do that, what are the other options to use the function from my shared library.

The shared library I'm talking about was compiled with gcc. The option to recompile it with LLVM is out of question, because I'm using some SSE4.2 intrinsics in it, which my version of LLVM can't generate code for.

Answer (score 0):

`llvm-link` is only used for linking together LLVM bitcode files. If you want to link those with a shared library, you're going to have to compile your bitcode to an object file and then link it with a regular linker.

More information about `llvm-link` and linking with LLVM bitcode in general is found here:

- [How to link a library with clang and llvm-link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13802383/242762)
- [llvm-link with external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12685976/242762)
- [How to generate machine code with llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13464259/242762)
- [How to link object to libraries with LLVM >= 3.1 ? ( no GNU ld )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13528474/242762)
- [How to replace llvm-ld with clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14595906/242762)